# Magento 2 static content deploy not compiling less files

Tags: magento2

I'm working on an theme based on blank theme (Magento 2.2.5) on developer mode as well as production mode the theme less files are not compiling using:

```
rm -R pub/static/*
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Images are loaded ok, not css. No errors using verbose. The only way is using grunt **both for development and production** for my theme what can i do?

Comment: Which mode are you one? Development, Production?

Comment: both development and production

Comment: Have you tried php bin/magento indexer:reindex?

Comment: yes, but i don't think is related.

Comment: I assume that folder permissions are correct

Comment: I had the same problem once when I had multiple languages and I haven't generated content bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy generate it for only en_US if you have different ones you need to specify them after deploy:

Comment: remove var/cache var/page_cache var/view_preprocessed folders as well along with pub/static... grunt is a preferable solution but still removing var folders can fix this issue!

Comment: already remove them, then running php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy same problem

Comment: As @Timothy mentioned, do you have multiple languages? If so, then try to deploy to those languages something like this `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy nl_NL en_US de_DE`

Answer (score 1):

Solving this issue is actually simple; just run the following command

Clear the var/cache and var/view_preprocessed directories by deleting the directory in

```
sudo rm -R pub/static/*
sudo rm -R var/cache
```

if you have to (sudo rm -R generated/code)

```
sudo rm -R var/view_preprocessed
sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Comment: does not compile less either. Seems to be a bug from 2.2.5 using blank as parent

Comment: very wrong and dangerous answer... If you remove all the folder you'll  either remove the .htaccess...

Comment: If you're not using apache you're safe to delete the ,htaccess. I use nginx and have no need for it for obvious reasons. Just saying.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in production mode, delete var/view_preprocessed and var/cache, run the CLI for setup upgrade and then static-content deploy. That should work.